# Using COUNTIF vs COUNTIFS using a single criteria. Is there a difference?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I've seen worksheets using `COUNTIFS()` function even when they've only specified a single criteria. I wanted to correct them on this by using only `COUNTIF()`. Is there a difference in speed/efficiency perhaps?

Comment: There is no difference. The difference is in SUMIF/SUMIFS, AVerageIF/AVERAGEIFS, etc. where the criteria range may or may not be the actionable range. Since the syntax flips on these some people (like me) just pretend that there is no such thing as SUMIF/AVERAGEIF and COUNTIF gets lumped in regardless of its suitability for that group.

Comment: @Jeeped It feels counter intuitive to me. If you have more criteria and ranges to check wouldn't countifs be less efficient? Previous experience strongly suggests you are right but why? What does "where the criteria range may or may not be the actionable range"  mean please?

Comment: @QHarr because you can have the criteria apply to the counted range or to a different range compared to the one being counted.

Comment: @QHarr - In SUMIF, the syntax is SUMIF(<sum_range>, <criteria>) **or** SUMIF(<criteria_range>, <criteria>, <sum_range>) so the syntax flips depending on whether <criteria_range> and <sum_range> are the same thing. On the other hand, SUMIFS(<sum_range>, <criteria_range>, <criteria>, ...) is consistent. Note that MS didn't bring in a new MAXIF, only MAXIFS.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks. I guess this is only for the case of countifs with one criteria though? Am I digging a deeper hole?

Comment: @QHarr well, consider a list of people who entered a nightclub and you want to count the ones who are male, over 18 and have a driving licence...

Comment: That is multiple criteria so I would expect it to be more efficient if only counting males for example. I realise there is something I am not getting here. I guess I need to step back and look with fresh eyes.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between is that **COUNTIF()** is designed for counting cells with a single condition in one range, whereas **COUNTIFS()** can evaluate different criteria in the same or in different ranges.

**COUNTIF()** function is used for counting cells within a specified range that meet a certain criterion, or condition.

```
COUNTIF(range, criteria)
```

**COUNTIFS()** function is purposed for counting cells across multiple ranges based on one or several conditions.

```
COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]…)
```

Comment: Apologies if there were any confusion: what I'm trying to ask if is there is any difference (in efficiency perhaps, or wherever else), if COUNTIFS is used as COUNTIF (meaning only one criteria is used).